# Change text styling - settextView getString

Tags: java, android, json

I have two strings that are pulled from json, need to change styling for both elements.

My code is:

```
    private void settextView(String json) throws JSONException {
        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(json);
        String[] tasks = new String[jsonArray.length()];
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject obj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
            tasks[i] = obj.getString("quote") + "\n\n" + obj.getString("name");

            TextView quote = null;
            quote.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));

            textView.setText(tasks[0]);

            setBtnCopyOnClick(tasks[0]); //Here


        }
    }
```

As you can see, I have tried to insert:

```
TextView quote = null;
            quote.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
```

However this doesn't do anything. Anyone have any ideas? I could be doing this the completely wrong way.
I would have had both strings separate in my .xml file, however it is pulled through as one.

Comment: I don't know, when i added the "wuote.setTextColor", it asked to add this in so i said yes..

Answer (score 0):

```
  TextView quote=null;
   
  quote=findViewById(R.id.textView1);
```

> this is not working because you give only null value to TextView;
>
> here textview1 is id of TextView in you xml file;
> replace textView1 with your textview id

Comment: Unfrotunaltey this does not help me set the colour for the two strings. I am aware the null lines are wrong now, but not sure what to replace with.